# Firefox addon to see the request

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is it possible to see the request which my browser send to the server. Or if it's some addon for firefox.

Comment: Very useful to see all HTTPS requests, which are obviously not shown by a sniffer like Wireshark, because they are encrypted.

Answer (score 7):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for firefox or [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) standalone

Answer (score 2):

webdeveloper addon
install it and in the "forms" tab see the "convert form methods".
Download it from : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/

Answer (score 1):

All the answers given so far are good, but I really like [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/), personally.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Live HTTP Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I just use the Web Developer Tools in Firefox. You can easily view the request using Web Console (Ctrl+Shift+K)

In addition, if you are interested in exploring the effects of various headers, such as say you are interested to tamper with/ block those requests, you may have a look at the firefox extension [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/).