# Using webcrawler to get data on site that's called from asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, python, html, http

I sent a GET request to this site and got the html body back:

https://www.itftennis.com/juniors/tournaments/tournament/info.aspx?tournamentid=1100042329

If you click on 'Results', you can then click on a different category and get the different players and data.

However, the data is not actually in this html body, it's loaded from the fucnction ajaxLoadTourResults. Is there anyway to use an HTTP request to get this data? Without hardcoding values for the eventId and such?

Comment: Possible duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365154/web-crawling-ajax-javascript-enabled-pages-using-java

Comment: Using python, not java.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Puppeteer's Tracing method to achieve this, take a look:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-tracing